# Is there a way to get to the numeric keyboard when entering text fields

Tags: 2.1-eclair, samsung-galaxy-s, keyboard

When you are entering text field entries on Android, you get the soft keyboard on my Samsung Galaxy S.

In the lower left corner there is the key that switches between the alphabetic characters and the keyboard with punctuations and digits (and smileys and so on).

Now if you have to enter a large number, this is a bit tricky - because the numeric keypad's keys are much bigger, it's much easier to enter numbers and digits.

Therefore, I was wondering if there is a way I haven't discovered , yet , to somehow **switch to the numeric keypad, even when entering text entries**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the gear button next to the ?123 button in the lower left, then click 3x4 keypad, then click the 123 button on the right. this way you will have a full 3x4 numeric keypad

Comment: That's it - all in all (look at my own answer) as was very close - I had noticed the 3x4 button , but found the old mobile keys on screen - I hadn't noticed the 123 button there.

Comment: what is the "gear" button? All I see is to the left of the ?123, is the Swype/OPT button.

Comment: betwen ?123 and space button. do you own galaxy S?

Comment: @pfctd You're using the Swype keyboard rather than the Samsung keyboard. See Joe Casadonte's answer for how to  switch to the numeric keypad quickly in Swype.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Swype simply drag from the Swype key to where the 5 is; Swype will change to the numeric keypad.

Comment: I was so happy when I figured this out.  Swyping from the Swype key to the SYM key also brings up a special keyboard for moving cursor and basic editing.

Answer (score 2):

All in all I found that pressing the '**keyboard selection**' box and choosing **handwriting box 1 or 2** is the easiest way. Not for entering 2 or 3 digits, but if you have to enter a lot of digits, this works quicker than having to type the numbers at the top row of the soft keyboard.

A shame, you can't switch to the numeric keyboard though.

Hope this helps some one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your keyboard
2. Click on the gear icon for settings
3. Click on preferences
4. Then turn on 'number rows'

This worked for me

Comment: Based on personal experience, this option is at least available on Gboard, but I'm not sure if it's also available on other Keyboard apps.